# THREE.KeyFrameAnimation is not defined

Tags: animation, three.js, collada

I'm using three js.`"three": "0.82.1"` and I found that [KeyFrameAnimation](https://threejs.org/docs/api/extras/animation/KeyFrameAnimation.html) is not [exist](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/animation/KeyFrameAnimation.js) more.

I think that something changed in three.js specification.

 Could anyone tell me how to handle collada keyframe animation in three js for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that KeyFrameAnimation now isn't a part of three.js and in theirs examples they includes KeyFrameAnimation from separate scripts. So I just copied scripts from examples into my project.